# Returning the promise of a resource's method

Tags: angularjs

Angular's `$resource` returns `get`, `save`, `query`, `remove`, `delete`. These functions take inthe resolved and rejected callbacks, i.e.

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.query(successCallback, rejectCallback);
```

Now, I would like to use the `then()`, `catch()` instead. I know that each of these guys returns a `$promise` that would have them. Currently, I could redo the above statement as

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.query()
    .$promise
    .then(successCallback)
    .catch(rejectCall);
```

But I would like to remove that intermediate `$promise`, i.e. I want the methods returned by `$resource` to the return the `promise` directly. What's the best way of doing this? Would a provide `decorator` work?

Comment: angular 1.3 returns a promise on a resource instance

Comment: On the resource itself?! Angular returns the methods on the `$resource` such as `save()`. And on those methods, it returns an object that has `$promise` as one of the parameters. So to use the promise, you still need to save `$resource(...).save().$promise.then()`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#resource-promises-are-resolved-with-the-resource-instance

Comment: @jack.the.ripper, that's interesting. The heading right about the section you sent me says `$then` is not removed, and you should use `$promise.then`. And I just tried `$then` and `then` and both gave me an undefined function call

Comment: I think you can't just get rid of the resource.query().$promise.then(callback) so easily, the only idea that comes to my mind is to wrap the resource into a promise but, unfortunately that's an antipattern so be careful. https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I guess I'll just leave it as it is then